# Ошибка при сериализации xml "ABC недоступен в силу его уровня защиты. Возможна обработка только общих типов"

Tags: c#, xml, сериализация

При сериализации xml вдает ошибку:

> System.InvalidOperationException: "Лабораторная_работа__1.Obertka недоступен в силу его уровня защиты. Возможна обработка только общих типов."

Код для сериализации :

```
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Obertka));
 var s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Obertka));
  using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename))
 {
 s.Serialize(writer, ob);
 }
 MessageBox.Show("Файл сохранен");
```

Код класса Obertka

```
class Obertka
{
    public List<Students> students { get; set; }
    public List<Groups> groups { get; set; }
    public List<Faculty> faculty { get; set; }

    public Obertka() { }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы его можно было сериализовать, класс должен быть публичным:

```
public class Obertka
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Когда я его делаю публичным , ругается на поля

Comment: Все классы (Students, Groups, Faculty) должны быть публичными